# Object flies away when adding Curve modifier

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

When I'm adding the curve modifier and adding a curve object - my object flies away

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: For the "Curve" modifier to work, the object and the curve must be in the same position and have the same rotation.

Comment: @LeonardoCáceres Thank you!!! It solves my problem

Comment: As @LeonardoCáceres said, the position and rotation for both object and curve must be same. It solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

To get the same rotation, select the object that's flying away, select "Object Constraint Properties" on the right panel, select "Copy Rotation" constraint from the pulldown and point it to your curve object.

(took me way to long to figure this out, posting detailed pic to save others my headache!)

[image]